# Do Google Chrome extensions work in popup windows opened with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So I'm working on creating an extension that'll need to work within a popup window that is triggered by my website... Standard Javascript...

```
function openwin(){
    window.open('http://stackoverflow.com','myname','height=100,width=100');
}
```

Now I need my extension to load within that window. Let's say the extension's purpose is to just alert a message, when I load that window the background.js should fire and do that, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chrome.windows.create(object createData, function callback)`

Creates (opens) a new browser with any optional sizing, position or default URL provided.

From: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/windows.html#method-create

Try this example:

```
var props = {
    url: "http://www.stackoverflow.com",
    height: "100",
    width: "100",
    type: "popup"
}

chrome.windows.create(props, function(windowObj){
    console.log("Here's the window object.");
    console.dir(windowObj);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer Larry. I prefer to keep the code within the scope of the website, and leave the extension to do modifications. That said, I did come up with a solution. Make sure you have the tabs permission applied, as well as any websites the popup may visit. From there, listen for new windows being created, and test against each one to see if the parameters match (ie. window.name is what you are looking for.)

Comment: At the time of my writing this, height is now needed to be integer. im using googlechrome v24

Comment: To get it to work I had to remove the quote marks on height etc. So height:100 not height:"100"

Answer (score 0):

Here's my answer after looking through the API. As I said, it checks each new window being created and checks the parameters of that window. Here's the code, which can be added to the background.js file of your extension:

```
chrome.windows.onCreated.addListener(function(win){
    chrome.windows.get(win.id,{populate:true},function(tabwin){
        setTimeout(function(){
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabwin.tabs[0].id,{code:"alert(JSON.stringify(window));",runAt:'document_idle'});
        },500);
    });
});
```